# Error using CyberSource's API for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, soap, soap-client, cybersource

[image: I get this error] I get an error when I use CyberSource's tutorial/demo code from their documentation.

http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Simple_Order_API_Clients/Client_SDK_SO_API.pdf Page: 220

Any help here? I have no clue what keysDirectory is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi all you have to do is add the key in config file like so...

```
<add key="cybs.keysDirectory" value="c:\keys\"/>
<add key="cybs.keyFilename" value="????"/>
```